# Django: Template does not exist

Tags: python, django

Please can you help me understand what I have done wrong here, I am sure it's a very simple problem but, I am new to django and especially the latest version...

I believe and as far to my research that I have routed my views to the best of my knowledge, please may you help identify my issue, I am getting an error:

"Page Not Found"

url.py from my app

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

views from my app

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from requests import request 

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'landing_page/index.html')
```

url from my project folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', include('comp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

urls from my project

and then here is my project and template folders, I have attached an image for your ease of helping me:

[image: workspace]

Comment: `path('/', include('comp.urls'))` remove the /

Comment: There’s no need to add a leading slash, because every URL has that. [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: Show us the `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py`.

Comment: `TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.py file, just add this:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

**EX:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], #Removed landing_page from here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
               #Removed libraries from here
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you, so I did that thanks, I get a different error now, at first i was getting a 404 error, now its telling me :
`
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'landing_page/index.html')
`
The error says: **TemplateDoesNotExist at /
landing_page/index.html**

Comment: instead of this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') try this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'landing_page' 'templates')

Comment: No i am unfortunately still getting the same error on the page rendering telling me the path cant be found

Comment: check the spelling of landing_page. it must be correct, if there is spelling wrong in render or in folder

Comment: can i share my repo with you because i cant see a spelling error at all

Comment: ok share it with me

Comment: Thank you so much https://github.com/trevthedev777/wearequantum

Comment: will let you know tomorrow

Comment: I have solved that error

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: Your template folder and static folder is not inside your project root. let's move these folders to your project root. move these two folders where manage.py file is present

Comment: After doing above thing, let's remove landing_page from DIRS in TEMPLATES variable in settings.py file

Comment: And also remove libraries from TEMPLATES variable in settings.py file. you can look my answer how i removed landing_page and libraries from TEMPLATES variable in settings.py file

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ALL YOUR HELP!!!! i learned a lot!